# How would I change my background through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I've tried a few different programs using regedit, but they have an about 50/50 chance of success. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't and I can't figure out why it isn't working. This is the program that is supposed to edit the registry then update it:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d C:\Users\Samuel.Elliott\Pictures\lambo.bmp /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 10 /f
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Comment: The first thing I note is that you're setting the value of `WallpaperStyle` to `10` , but your question is about changing the wallpaper, not it's style. To change the wallpaper, including settings such as `WallpaperStyle` and `TileWallpaper` I would suggest you [create a theme file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/themesfileformat-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead. If as you say it works 50/50, it follows that you've provided us with only a portion of your script, and that portion in isolation is irrelevant to your question. Please post the entire failing code.

Comment: oops, my bad. i accidentally posted the wrong one. I'll change it real quick

Comment: Brakui, can you please explain what you mean by "Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't". Do you mean exactly that code with exactly the same path and image file in your value  data? or do the problems occur when one or more of those things change, or possibly when run on other PC's? The reason I ask is that the code should work in exactly the same way, every time you run it under the same profile in the same environment, unless one or more things change. We need to determine those in order to help you.